# Get value of each on blur() event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page which contain a bunch of text area generated by a PHP script. There is a hidden input type that contains an id of a variable. Basically what I want to do is to call the .ajax() JQuery method on .blur() on any of the text areas and pass the value of the textarea + the id from the hidden input. 
All of my text areas are named like this: tr1,tr2,tr3,etc. And the hidden fields:tr_id1,tr_id2,etc

So how can I get the value from both elements so I can use them somewhere else?

Comment: It's a little bit confusing. Could you please explain it betteR?

Comment: Fixed. Look at the code in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may give you an idea

**HTML**

```
<textarea name="tr1"></textarea>
<input type="hidden" name="tr_id1" value="1" />
<br />
<textarea name="tr2"></textarea>
<input type="hidden" name="tr_id2" value="2"/>
```

​
**JS**

```
​$(function(){
    $('textarea').on('blur', function(e){
        var txtAval=$(this).val();
        var txtId=$(this).prop('name').replace('tr','');
        var txtHval=$('input:hidden[name="tr_id'+txtId+'"]').val();

        // txtAval contains textarea's value and txtHval contains text input's value

       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "some_url",
           data: {txtarea:txtAval, txthidden:txtId}
          //or
          //data: "txtarea="+txtAval+"&txthidden="+txtId
        }).done(function(msg) {
            // ...
        });
    });
});​
```

**jQuery ajax reference:** [**Here.**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

[**See the values on the console here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/4VfzG/1/)

Comment: Thanks. That was exactly what I was looking for. In a side note did you use something else other than fiddle.net and console to debugger the script?

Comment: Thanks and no, nothing other than fiddle.